# How to Prioritize Meta Descriptions in Nuxt2 Components Over Default Value in nuxt.config.js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm encountering an issue with my Nuxt2 application where I've defined meta descriptions both in individual components and in the nuxt.config.js file. However, when I'm doing a SEMrush scan, the default value set in nuxt.config.js is being prioritized over the descriptions specified in the components. I noticed that this happens with the pages that are generated, and sometimes it takes longer to load them. To be more precise, when I'm accessing a page with this problem, before the whole content is rendered, I get a loading screen like this. I think this also might be an issue, even though i set loading: false in my nuxt.config.js file :
[image]

Here's a simplified version of my setup:

In nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  head: {
    meta: [
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Default meta description' }
    ]
  }
}
```

And in my component file:

```
    head() {
    // @ts-ignore
    const pageHead = this.pageHead()
    const pageData = this.pageData as PageData
    const yoastDescription = pageData?.yoast_head_json?.description
    return {
      ...pageHead,
      title: `About`,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'og:title',
          name: 'og:title',
          content: 'About',
        },
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: yoastDescription,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:description',
          name: 'og:description',
          content: yoastDescription,
        },
        ...pageHead?.meta,
      ],
    }
  },
  async asyncData(context) {
    const { store } = context

    await store.dispatch('common/setupPageLight', context)

    const pageData = await store.dispatch('wp/fetchPageBySlug', {
      context,
      slug: 'about-nuxt',
    })
    store.commit('common/isBusy', false)

    return {
      pageData,
    }
  },
```

I also mention the fact that when I open my dev tools and check the head tag, all the information regarding the meta tags is there, and it's unique, it's not the default one.

I thought that having a default value was the main issue even though it sounds silly, and I tried to remove it. When I did it, SEMrush saw it as I did not have any kind of description, so I put it back.

Despite having unique meta descriptions in each component, the SEMrush scan consistently picks up the default description. How can I ensure that the descriptions specified in my components take precedence over the default value?